# How to change a property of a button according to the button that had been click?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to change the property of the button that had been clicked. I can't figure out how to do it based on the button that was clicked. I don't want to duplicate the method for each button.

This is my code:

```
private void GetPlayerChoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (playerX.Turn == true)
    {
        button1.Text = playerX.Name;
        button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 15, 0);
        playerX.Turn = false;
        playerO.Turn = true;
    }
    if (playerO.Turn == true)
    {
        button1.Text = playerO.Name;
        button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(96, 255, 40);
        playerX.Turn = true;
        playerO.Turn = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's !!! It helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your button in the sender parameter of the eventhandler.
So you can try:

```
Button button = sender as Button;
if (button != null)
{
    button.Text = "Clicked";
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! that's exactly what I meant.